# Differentiating and integral with respect to limits of the integral

Tags: calculus

I'm a little confused on a calculus problem. I'm solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(\xi)d\xi$ and found the solution to be $c g(x+ct) - (-c) g(x-ct)$ but I'm not sure why this is. Could someone help explain this?

Comment: Are you sure the problem was $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and not $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule combined.  For example,  take 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(h(x))-F(g(x))\right)$$
$$=f(h(x))h'(x) - f(g(x))g'(x) $$

Comment: Am i mistaken to think it should be $\frac{d}{dx}(F(h(x)) - F(g(x)))$?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark nope,  you are absolutely right...  My fault for being careless!

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly.  As I'm sure you've noticed,  to get your form into mine just let $h(x, t, c)  =x + ct$ and $g(x, t, c)  = x-ct$.  Note that this doesn't affect the use of the formula I give,  as you have a partial derivative out front,  so only $x$ is treated as a variable,  regardless of whether $c$ and $t$ are constants or not.

Comment: Yes, but in that case: $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial ~~}{\partial~x}\int\limits_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(\xi)\operatorname d \xi ~= & ~ \dfrac{\partial (x+ct)}{\partial x\qquad} \cdot g(x+ct)-\dfrac{\partial (x-ct)}{\partial x\qquad} \cdot g(x-ct)
\\= & ~g(x+ct)-g(x-ct)\end{align}$$ However: $$\frac{\partial ~~}{\partial~\color{red}{ t}}\int\limits_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(\xi)\operatorname d \xi ~=~ c~g(x+ct)-(-c)~g(x-ct)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp hmm... Good point.  The OP must be calculating the derivative with respect to $t$ instead or else derived the wrong answer.